# How to implement a frontend view of a backend countup timer in java?

Tags: java

Trying to implement a timer for my game that I'm making. I have a backend class `Game` that has an `int timeElapsed()` method. This gives me elapsed time since the start in milliseconds. I also have a front end view that needs an update of this elapsed time. What is the best way to synchronize these two values? I could set up a daemon to call `game.timeElapsed()` every second, but it seems that there must be a better way to do this.

Another idea I had was to put some timekeeping in the frontend, but this seems like a violation of separation of responsibilities.

The `Stopwatch` class that I'm using to keep track of time does not support callbacks.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`java.util.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class, to periodically update the view. Call `game.timeElapsed()` in each iteration, don't keep two `Stopwatch`-objects around.

Comment: Should I call it every second, then?

Comment: Yes, you give the timer a task that calls game.timeElapsed() (and updates the view), and you schedule it to be executed every second.

Comment: -1 This is just wrong... using a whole Timer for such a trivial task? Can't you just call game.timeElapsed() every frame?

Comment: @Vuntic, *what?* This approach is perfectly fine. Most Java GUIs are event-driven so there will not even be a "render loop" as you seem to assume.